# Drawing disappears on canvas (Drawn using fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a T-shirt design studio. Right now i'm working on drawing functionality. User can draw anything on the tshirt.

Fabric's docs states that drawing mode can be enabled by adding `isDrawingMode: true` to the fabric canvas element. So i added it and i was able to draw lines on the canvas.

But those lines dissapear if i do something else. [Here's](http://catherineasanov.com/sml123/html/DS/index.php) the demo.

Clicking on the `Accessories` tab enables the `isDrawingMode` and hence lines can be drawn on the canvas.

But if you open `Choose Style` and select `BACK` option. Again open `Choose Style` and select `FRONT`, those lines dissapear.

Why those lines are not binding with the canvas? i even tried `renderAll()` method stated in the docs.

Comment: That's how canvas works, you must be prepared to redraw when necessary.

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/weMbr/